# how to modify simple assembler code to be more realistic?

Tags: python, assembly, mips

[i have implmented simple assembler that assembles set of 15 mips instructions, the program gets the instruction from the user as shown and print the corresponding machine code to output txt file, my question is how to modify the code such that the assembler takes infinite no. instructions till the user abort the program him self & print each 32-bit instruction in new line in the output file]

here is the code:

```
inst = raw_input("enter your instruction operation:")

if ((inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'd' and inst[2] == 'd' and inst[3] != 'i') or (inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'n' and inst[2] == 'd' and inst[3] != 'i') or (inst[0] == 'o' and inst[1] == 'r'and inst[2] != 'i') or (inst[0] == 'n' and inst[1] == 'o' and inst[2] == 'r') or (inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'u' and inst[2] == 'b') or (inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 'l') or(inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 't')):

        Rs = raw_input("enter the first operand:")
        for i in range (0,32):
         if(Rs == '$'+ str(i)):
            rs = "{0:05b}".format(i)
            opcode = '000000'
            Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
            Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs))
            Mc_file.close()
        Rt = raw_input("enter the 2nd operand:")
        for i in range (0,32):
         if(Rt == '$'+ str(i)):
            rt = "{0:05b}".format(i)
            opcode = '000000'
            Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
            Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt))
            Mc_file.close()
        Rd = raw_input("enter the destination operand:")
        for i in range (0,32):
         if(Rd == '$'+ str(i)):
            rd = "{0:05b}".format(i)
            opcode = '000000'
            shamt ='00000'
            Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
            Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt)
            Mc_file.close()

        if(inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'd' and inst[2] == 'd'):
              ass_inst = str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rd) + ',' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt)
              print "your assembly instruction is: %s" % (ass_inst)
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100000'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'n' and inst[2] == 'd'):
              ass_inst = str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rd) + ',' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt)
              print "your assembly instruction is: %s" % (ass_inst)
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100100'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 'o' and inst[1] == 'r'):
              ass_inst = str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rd) + ',' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt)
              print "your assembly instruction is: %s" % (ass_inst)
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100101'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 'n' and inst[1] == 'o' and inst[2] == 'r'):
              ass_inst = str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rd) + ',' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt)
              print "your assembly instruction is: %s" % (ass_inst)
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100111'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'u' and inst[2] == 'b'):
              ass_inst = str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rd) + ',' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt)
              print "your assembly instruction is: %s" % (ass_inst)
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('100010'))
              Mc_file.close()
              """ if(inst[0] == 'j' and inst[1] == 'r'):
              ass_inst = str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rd) + ',' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt)
              print "your assembly instruction is: %s" % (ass_inst)
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str('00000') + str('00000') +str(rd) + shamt + str('001000'))
              Mc_file.close()"""
        if(inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 'l'):
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('000000'))
              Mc_file.close()
        if(inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'l' and inst[2] == 't'):
              Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
              Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) +str(rd) + shamt + str('101010'))
              Mc_file.close()
elif (inst[0] == 'l' and inst[1] == 'w'):
    Rs = raw_input("enter the first operand:",)
    for i in range (0,32):
     if(Rs == '$'+ str(i)):
            rs = "{0:05b}".format(i)
    Rt = raw_input("enter the destination operand:")
    for i in range (0,32):
     if(Rt == '$'+ str(i)):
            rt = "{0:05b}".format(i)
    imediate = input("Enter the value of the offset:")
    ass_inst = str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(str(imediate) + '('+ str(Rt) + ')')

    print " Entered assembly instruction is: %s " % ass_inst
    opcode ='100011'
    imd = "{0:016b}".format(imediate)
    Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
    Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) + str(imd))
    Mc_file.close()
elif (inst[0] == 's' and inst[1] == 'w'):
    Rs = raw_input("enter the destination operand:")
    for i in range (0,32):
     if(Rs == '$'+ str(i)):
            rs = "{0:05b}".format(i)
    Rt = raw_input("enter the source operand:")
    for i in range (0,32):
     if(Rt == '$'+ str(i)):
            rt = "{0:05b}".format(i)
    imediate = input("Enter the value of the offset:")
    ass_inst = str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(str(imediate) + '('+ str(Rt) + ')')
    print "your assembly instruction is: %s" % (ass_inst)
    imd = "{0:016b}".format(imediate)
    opcode = '101011'
    Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
    Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) + str(imd))
    Mc_file.close()

elif inst[0] == 'j' and inst[1] == 'r':
    dr = raw_input("enter the destination register:")
    inst_ = str(inst) + ' ' + str(dr)
    print "The entered assembly instruction is %s" % inst_
    for i in range(0,32):
     if(dr == '$'+ str(i)):
        addrss = "{0:026b}".format(i)
        Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        opcode = '000011'
        Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(addrss))
        Mc_file.close()
elif inst[0] == 'b' and inst[1] == 'e' and inst[2] == 'q':
       Rs = raw_input("enter the first operand to be compared:",)
       for i in range (0,32):
        if(Rs == '$'+ str(i)):
            rs = "{0:05b}".format(i)
       Rt = raw_input("enter the second operand to be compared:")
       for i in range (0,32):
        if(Rt == '$'+ str(i)):
            rt = "{0:05b}".format(i)
       imediate = input("Enter the branch target address:")
       ass_inst = (str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt) + ' ' + str(imediate))
       print " Entered assembly instruction is: %s " % ass_inst
       imd = "{0:016b}".format(imediate)
       opcode = '000100'
       Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
       Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) + str(imd))
       Mc_file.close() 
elif (inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'n' and inst[2] == 'd'and inst[3] == 'i'):
     Rs = raw_input("enter the first operand:")
     for i in range (0,32):
        if(Rs == '$'+ str(i)):
            rs = "{0:05b}".format(i)
     Rt = raw_input("enter the second operand:")
     for i in range (0,32):
        if(Rt == '$'+ str(i)):
            rt = "{0:05b}".format(i)
     imediate = input("Enter the Imediate number:")
     ass_inst = (str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt) + ' ' + str(imediate))
     print " Entered assembly instruction is: %s " % ass_inst
     imd = "{0:016b}".format(imediate)
     opcode = '000100'
     Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
     Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) + str(imd))
     Mc_file.close() 

elif (inst[0] == 'o' and inst[1] == 'r' and inst[2] == 'i'):
     Rs = raw_input("enter the first operand:")
     for i in range (0,32):
        if(Rs == '$'+ str(i)):
            rs = "{0:05b}".format(i)
     Rt = raw_input("enter the second operand:")
     for i in range (0,32):
        if(Rt == '$'+ str(i)):
            rt = "{0:05b}".format(i)
     imediate = input("Enter the Imediate number:")
     ass_inst = (str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt) + ' ' + str(imediate))
     print " Entered assembly instruction is: %s " % ass_inst
     imd = "{0:016b}".format(imediate)
     opcode = '001101'
     Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
     Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) + str(imd))
     Mc_file.close() 
elif (inst[0] == 'a' and inst[1] == 'd' and inst[2] == 'd'and inst[3] == 'i'):
     Rs = raw_input("enter the first operand:")
     for i in range (0,32):
        if(Rs == '$'+ str(i)):
            rs = "{0:05b}".format(i)
     Rt = raw_input("enter the second operand:")
     for i in range (0,32):
        if(Rt == '$'+ str(i)):
            rt = "{0:05b}".format(i)
     imediate = input("Enter the Imediate number:")
     ass_inst = (str(inst) + ' ' + str(Rs) + ',' + str(Rt) + ' ' + str(imediate))
     print " Entered assembly instruction is: %s " % ass_inst
     imd = "{0:016b}".format(imediate)
     opcode = '001000'
     Mc_file = open("output.txt", "w")
     Mc_file.write(str(opcode) + str(rs) + str(rt) + str(imd))
     Mc_file.close() 
else:
    print "Not supported operation!"
```

Comment: You should learn to use tables.  Put the instructions in a table and loop through it to find the match. It reduces repetition in your code.

Comment: yes thanks for this advic i will try to keep it in mind next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `while True` to loop indefinitely:

```
while True:
    inst = raw_input("enter your instruction operation or 'q' to quit:")
    if inst.lower() in ("q", "quit"):
        break
    # rest of code goes here
```

You can either `open` the file before this loop and `write` a line at a time, or re-open the file each time through the loop in `'a'` ("append") mode.

Comment: i did what u said but it assembles the last input instruction only in 32 bit line

Comment: Yes, because you open the file in `'w'` ("(over)write") mode. Read my whole answer.

Comment: ok when i enter 3 instructions the machine code of the three aligns in the same line !
they should be printed each instruction in a single line

Comment: You need to include the line breaks explicitly; use `'\n'` at the end of each line.

Comment: thanks jonrsharpe it works, what if i want to make this executable out side the IDE i mean i can run this simple assembler from the desktop can i do this & how ?

Comment: Look into tools like pyfreeze and py2exe, you can also run Python scripts from the command line